# Cost of instruction jumps in assembly

Tags: performance, assembly, x86

I've had always been curious about the cost of jumps in assembly.

```
cmp ecx, edx
je SOME_LOCATION # What's the cost of this jump?
```

Does it need to do a search in a lookup table for each jumps or how does it work?

Comment: From Intel's manual: _"The Jcc instruction does not support far jumps (jumps to other code segments). When the target for the conditional
jump is in a different segment, use the opposite condition from the condition being tested for the Jcc instruction,
and then access the target with an unconditional far jump (JMP instruction) to the other segment."_

Comment: Not deterministic.  The destination independent of segment (note a segment is 16 bytes so a high percentage of the time you are jumping to another segment) can be found at one of a number of possibly places that all take a different amount of time to fetch.  already prefetched, l1 cache, l2 cache...system memory...

Comment: The question may need to be updated, removing `to another code segment`. I'm not aware of an assembler that allows anything but "flat" model in 32 bit mode. The question could be asking about jumps in 16 bit real mode, (32 bit operands can be used in real mode on 386 or later processors). In either case, on a recent X86 processor, the main cost will be if branch prediction assumed the branch would not occur.

Comment: @rcgldr I'm not super familiar with assembly actually. But what I'm trying to say is to another label I think, without change in mode. I edited it now thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a jump doesn’t do a search. The assembler resolves the label to an address, which in most cases is then converted to an offset from the current instruction. The address or offset is encoded in the instruction. At run time, the processor loads the address into the IP register or adds the offset to the current value of the IP register (along with all the other effects discussed by @Brendan).

There is a type of jump instruction that can be used to get the destination from a table. The jump instruction reads the address from a memory location. (The instruction specifies a single location, so there still is no “search”.) This instruction could look something like this:

```
jmp table[eax*4]
```

where eax is the index of the entry in the table containing the address to jump to.

Answer (score 5):

Originally (e.g. 8086) the cost of a jump wasn't much different to the cost of a `mov`.

Later CPUs added caches, which meant some jumps were faster (because the code they jump to is in the cache) and some jumps were slower (because the code they jump to isn't in the cache).

Even later CPUs added "out of order" execution, where conditional branches (e.g. `je SOME_LOCATION`) would have to wait until the flags from "previous instructions that happen to be executed in parallel" became known.

This means that a sequence like

```
mov esi, edi 
cmp ecx, edx 
je SOME_LOCATION
```

can be slower than rearranging it to

```
cmp ecx, edx 
mov esi, edi 
je SOME_LOCATION
```

to increase the chance that the flags would be known.

Even later CPUs added speculative execution. In this case, for conditional branches the CPU just takes a guess at where it will branch to before it actually knows (e.g. before the flags are known), and if it guesses wrong it'll just pretend that it didn't execute the wrong instructions. More specifically, the speculatively executed instructions are tagged at the start of the pipeline and held at the end of the pipeline (at retirement) until the CPU knows if they can be committed to visible state or if they have to be discarded.

After that things just got more complicated, with fancier methods of doing branch prediction, additional "branch target" buffers, etc.

Far jumps that change the code segment are more expensive. In real mode it's not so bad because the CPU mostly only does "CS.base = value * 16" when `CS` is changed. For protected mode it's a table lookup (to find GDT or LDT entry), decoding the entry, deciding what to do based on what kind of entry it is, then a pile of protection checks. For long mode it's vaguely similar. All of this adds more uncertainty (e.g. with the table entry be in cache?).

On top of all of this there's things like TLB misses. For example, `jmp [indirectAddress]` can cause a TLB miss at `indirectAddress` then a TLB miss at the stack top then a TLB miss at the new instruction pointer; where each TLB miss can cost a few hundred cycles.

Mostly; the cost of a jump can be anything from 0 cycles (for a correctly predicted jump) to maybe 1000 cycles; depending on which CPU it is, what kind of jump, what is in caches, what branch prediction predicts, cache/TLB misses, how fast/slow RAM is, and anything I may have forgotten.

Comment: Does a jump avoid a search(imposing a logn penalty)? a `mov` already know the address by its operands, so it doesn't need to do a search. Why I'm asking is because it uses a symbol name and somehow it has to get the address from that symbol name.

Comment: @einstein: in the machine code, a `jmp` is encoded as `jmp rel32` or `jmp rel8`.  It's simply an offset added to EIP.  The assembler + linker take care of resolving the symbol to a numeric value, the same way they do for `mov eax, [symbol_name]`.

Comment: `cmp/je` can macro-fuse into a single uop on Core2 and later (and Bulldozer and later), so the first arrangement is more efficient on modern x86.